Probems to translate postgres query to Diesel with NOT IN
I have two tables, achievements, and user_achievements. The structure is similar to the following one:
achievements
--------------
| id | name  |
|  1 | one   |
|  2 | two   |
|  3 | three |
--------------

user_achievements
---------------------------------
| id | user_id | achievement_id |
|  1 |       1 |              1 |
|  2 |       1 |              2 |
|  3 |       2 |              3 |
---------------------------------

I also have the following query to retrieve the achievements not "achieved" by one user:
SELECT a.* FROM achievements as a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT ua.achievement_id FROM user_achievements as ua WHERE user_id = 2);

So basically I want to query the entries in achievements table that one particular user did not achieve. The result of the previous query is:
--------------
| id | name  |
|  1 | one   |
|  2 | two   |
--------------

But I don't know how to "translate" that to Diesel.
I have the following:
pub fn get_achievements_not_achieved_by_user(&self, the_user_id: i32) -> QueryResult<Vec<Achievement>> {
        let conn = &mut self.pool.get().unwrap();
      achievements.filter(!id.eq_any(user_achievements.select(achievement_id).filter(user_id.eq(the_author_id)))).get_results(conn)
}

I can't find something like not_eq_any, any idea?

You're looking for .ne_all() in Diesel:

Creates a SQL NOT IN statement.

